# Search bar in Swift not searching with a PHP file

Tags: ios, swift

I have no errors in my code but there's definitely something missing. Also there when I press done in the keyboard nothing happens. It might have to do with the search bar function or the table view function. I also have a Search.swift file and I will add it. Any suggestions would be very helpful, I feel really stuck.

`SearchBarViewController`:

```
let url = URL(string: "http://127.0.0.1/musicfiles/search.php")
var filteredData = [String]()
var shouldShowSearchResults = false
var search: [Search] = []
var filePath = "http://127.0.0.1/musicfiles/search.php"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    searchBar.delegate = self
    searchBar.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.done
    
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, snapshot, error) in
        let retrievedList = String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        print(retrievedList!)
        self.parseSongs(data: retrievedList!)
    }
    task.resume()
}

func parseSongs (data: String) {
    if (data.contains("*")) {
        let dataArray = (data as String).split(separator: "*").map(String.init)
        for item in dataArray {
            let itemData = item.split(separator: ",").map(String.init)
            let searchSong = Search(songname: itemData[0])
            search.append(searchSong!)
            
            for s in search {
                print(s.searchSongName())
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return search.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! DataCell
    let song = search[indexPath.row].searchSongName()
    cell.congigureCell(text: song)
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let searchSong = search[indexPath.row].searchSongName()
    let fileURLString = "\(filePath)\(searchSong)"
    print(fileURLString)
}

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    if searchBar.text == nil || searchBar.text == "" {
        
        shouldShowSearchResults = false
        
        view.endEditing(true)
        
        filteredData.removeAll()
    } else {
        shouldShowSearchResults = true
        filteredData = search.filter({ (songName) -> Bool in
            songName.searchSongName().range(of: searchText) != nil
        })
            .map { $0.songname }
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are loading your data into an array called `search`.

When you filter your data, you are placing the filtered data into an array called `filteredData`.

Your tableview always shows the contents of `search`, so you never see the results of your filtering.

You could check whether `filteredData` is empty and then return data from that array or `search` in `numberOfRows` and `cellForRow`.  Personally I would always use `filteredData` and make sure that it holds the contents of `search` when the filter string is empty.

```
var filteredData = [Search]()
func parseSongs (data: String) {
    if (data.contains("*")) {
        let dataArray = (data as String).split(separator: "*").map(String.init)
        for item in dataArray {
            let itemData = item.split(separator: ",").map(String.init)
            let searchSong = Search(songname: itemData[0])
            search.append(searchSong!)

            for s in search {
                print(s.searchSongName())
            }
            self.filterData = self.search
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return filteredData.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! DataCell
    let song = filteredData[indexPath.row].searchSongName()
    cell.congigureCell(text: song)
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let searchSong = filteredData[indexPath.row].searchSongName()
    let fileURLString = "\(filePath)\(searchSong)"
    print(fileURLString)
}

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    if (searchBar.text ?? "").isEmpty {
        view.endEditing(true)

        filteredData = search
    } else {
        filteredData = search.filter({ (songName) -> Bool in
            songName.searchSongName().range(of: searchText) != nil
        })
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```